# How to create a table with different alignments in each row?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I would like to create a table that looks like this, preferably one that allows me to use enumitem in the 'table' :

[image]

As you can see, the alignment for the first row is centered but the subsequent rows are left aligned. Thanks.

Comment: You could use one big `p` type column for the table and for the first row use `\multicolumn{1}{c}{Learning Outcomes}`.

Comment: Another viable solution would be a package like `tcolorbox` (which might be overkill for this simple looking result, but would add easy page breakability and allow more fancy looking boxes).

Comment: Is it possible to use arrays for this?

Comment: Do you mean the environment `array`? `tabular` is effectively the same but with text mode (what's what you want, as the contents are text not maths).

Comment: Or did you mean to achieve the stuff in the braces which I wrote to describe the advantages of `tcolorbox`? Page breakable would be hard to do, as a `tabular` is one cell. `longtable` could fix that (it is page breakable), but I think not in the midst of a `p` row. And the fancy looks are not possible with `tabular`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a `tabular` you could use

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[]{|p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\arrayrulewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}|}
  \hline
  \rowcolor{gray!25}
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Learning Outcomes}\\
  \hline
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item thingy
    \item thingy
  \end{enumerate}\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Small appetizer for `tcolorbox` (the `breakable` key makes the box page breakable if it is a big one):

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1]{colframe=gray,fonttitle=\bfseries,adjusted
title=\centering#1,breakable}

\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}{Learning Outcomes}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item thingy
    \item thingy
  \end{enumerate}
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What do the bits after begin tabular do? Especially \dimexpr, \tabcolsep and \relax.

Comment: @ChungRenKhoo `\dimexpr` lets you calculate a dimension based on simple maths. It absorbs every dimension/number following after it which are connected by correct maths operations. `\relax` stops this absorption to make sure that it can't absorb more than I want it to. So the stuff between `\dimexpr` and `\relax` is the width of the `p` type column. `\linewidth` should be self explanatory, `\arrayrulewidth` is the width of the vertical rules, `\tabcolsep` is the separation between the text and those rules (basically the padding which is added on both sides of each table column).

Comment: @ChungRenKhoo This makes sure that the table takes up the whole line but doesn't produce an overfull `\hbox` error.

Comment: If I would like to add more columns to the second box (it looks amazing btw) how do I go about doing that? e.g. Instead of just "Learning Outcomes", what if I want to have another column for "Random Stuff"?

Comment: @ChungRenKhoo there is the `raster column` key in `tcolorbox`, but I don't know whether you'd like the output. You can take a look at the [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox).